# Menus in the window's title bar

Tags: window, menu-bar

I want window menus to stay in the window's title bar and so have selected
System Settings > Appearance > Behaviour > Show the menus for a Window.  In the window's title bar

If I maximise the window the window's menus ignore that choice and jump up onto the top panel. Is this really supposed to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is supposed to be like that.

Comment: Oh :-( I'd came back to Ubuntu with 14.04 as I thought some of the Unity stuff had been sorted, but that's only half way there.

Comment: Since the Window's titlebar dissapears into the panel, the menubar will, of course, also move to the panel...